# How to share a image from Application Cache with ContentProvider

Tags: android, share, android-contentprovider, application-cache, android-sharing

i have a ContentProvider on my app, i use it to share images from assets folder. I used the solution proposed here: http://www.nowherenearithaca.com/2012/03/too-easy-using-contentprovider-to-send.html

Now i need to share images stored on the cache folder of my app. Would be nice to do it using the ContentProvider, but i can't find info about how to do it.

It is possible? If not, wich is the correct way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If "the cache folder" is `getCacheDir()`, [use `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

If "the cache folder" is `getExternalCacheDir()`, [try my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider).

If you really want to bake this into your own provider, you would need to override `openFile()` and use `ParcelFileDescriptor.openFile()` to create a `ParcelFileDescriptor` on your desired file. You would also need to extend your `getMimeType()` and `query()` methods to return the MIME type and filename/size, respectively. It is likely to be easier just to drop in one of the canned implementations.